# How can I condition the time column?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column representing 24 hours.
Data comes in every 15 minutes.
For example, at 10:15, the value is entered in the DateTime column of the 10H column.
But... The client wants to set the standard for the day at 6:30 a.m. and set it to 6:30 the next day.
If you look at the column below, should sum the value from column 6h.. Is there any way?

```
DateTime             0H  1H   ..6H....7H...8H..9H..10H..~23H
2020 11 10 00:00:00  979 958 
2020 11 10 00:15:00  987 954 
2020 11 10 00:30:00  987 958 
2020 11 10 00:45:00  960 956 
2020 11 11 00:00:00    0 0 
2020 11 11 00:15:00    0 0 
2020 11 11 00:30:00    0 0 
2020 11 11 00:45:00    0 0 
2020 11 12 00:00:00  995 995 
2020 11 12 00:15:00  991 993 
2020 11 12 00:30:00 1000 993 
2020 11 12 00:45:00  993 996
```

[image]

```
I want value
2020-11-15 06:30 ~ 2020-11-16 06:30 values sum
```

Comment: before anything... why don't have the [Datetime] column have hr in it... why this abomination of schema even exist..

Comment: also pls provide the expect output. Kinda confuse about what you actually want.

Comment: Please translate your explanation to well-organized data and well organized expected results to support us to help you.

Comment: I'm lost.  You have rows created every 15 minutes and hours pivoted across.  What does the data really look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider breaking hour blocks into separate `SELECT` segments that add corresponding hour columns. Then, bind all parts together by `UNION ALL`. Finally, aggregate all hour blocks for final `SUM`.

Below sums all values between `2020-11-15 06:30 - 2020-11-16 06:30` (not including upper limit). Be sure to fill in the abbreviated `...` for needed columns:

```sql
SELECT SUM(sub.HoursTotal) AS DayTotal
FROM
   (
    -- PARTIAL HOUR - 6:30 AM - 6:45 AM
    SELECT [6h] AS HoursTotal
    FROM myTable
    WHERE logdatetime BETWEEN '2020 11-15 00:30:00' AND  
                              '2020 11-15 00:45:00'

    UNION ALL

    -- FULL HOURS - 7:00 AM - 23:00 PM
    SELECT [7h] + [8h] + ... + [23h] AS HoursTotal
    FROM myTable
    WHERE logdatetime BETWEEN '2020 11-15 00:00:00' AND  
                              '2020 11-15 00:45:00'

    UNION ALL

    -- FULL HOURS - 12:00 AM - 5:00 AM
    SELECT [0h] + [1h] + ... + [5h] AS HoursTotal
    FROM myTable
    WHERE logdatetime BETWEEN '2020 11-16 00:00:00' AND  
                              '2020 11-16 00:45:00'
 
    UNION ALL

    -- PARTIAL HOUR - 6:00 AM - 6:15 AM
    SELECT [6h] AS HoursTotal
    FROM myTable
    WHERE logdatetime BETWEEN '2020 11-16 00:00:00' AND  
                              '2020 11-16 00:15:00'
  ) sub
```

Of course, ideally your table maintains a normalized structure of long format with two columns for datetime and value. Then, querying is much easier:

```
logDateTimewithHour   Value
2020 11-15 00:00:00     ###
2020 11-15 00:15:00     ###
2020 11-15 00:30:00     ###
2020 11-15 00:45:00     ###
2020 11-15 01:00:00     ###
2020 11-15 01:15:00     ###
2020 11-15 01:30:00     ###
2020 11-15 01:45:00     ###
...                     ...
2020 11-16 22:00:00     ###
2020 11-16 22:15:00     ###
2020 11-16 22:30:00     ###
2020 11-16 22:45:00     ###
2020 11-16 23:00:00     ###
2020 11-16 23:15:00     ###
2020 11-16 23:30:00     ###
2020 11-16 23:45:00     ###
```

```sql
SELECT SUM(Value) AS DayTotal
FROM myLongTable
WHERE logDateTimewithHour BETWEEN '2020 11-15 06:30:00'
                              AND '2020 11-16 06:15:00'
```